# CSS - Boot Strap Disable/Remove Selector All (*)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I included the Bootstrap style file (bootstrap.min.css), it conflicted with my other styles and menu, which makes the page displays incorrectly. I have found this selector below in the Bootstrap CSS file causes the issue. If I download and store the bootstrap file locally, remove that code block, my page will work correctly. However, I will loss other useful options such as "glyphicon".

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
```

If I include the bootstrap files using CDN like this *(which will mess up my page styles because of the above selector `*{}`)*, is there a way in my page `<style></style>` that can remove or disable that block of code above when it loads?

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `* { box-sizing: content-box }` in your custom CSS file. If that doesn't work, add `!important` at the end. Note that this will remove it from all of the bootstrap classes as well, so you will probably have to do it to each individual element instead of using the global selector.

Comment: *{box-sizing: content-box} is the default. So you will need to override border-box with this. Do it in the project after wherever bootstrap compiles to, as CSS styles cascade and the override shouldnt be overriden by the bootstrap code :)

Comment: I suggest to override it only where you need to as `border-box` is the new default. You should actually modify your design to fit this box model in my opinion.

Comment: As @Jake mentioned, `border-box` is a preferred option, since it helps you provide some consistency to the way the element's space is calculated; Bootstrap adds this so its components display correctly... So if you can't change your styles to fit the `border-box` model, then just change **your** styles to `content-box !important` where its necessary, but I don't recommend overriding the Bootstrap property

Comment: The `* { box-sizing: content-box }` works. Thank you everyone for helping.